# Turning the read more link into a button

Tags: read-more

I want to change the read more text to translate it and add a background to it to make it look more like a button. As it is done here: http://unaventananuevayork.com/. I´m using ultimatum theme and would appreciate answers for dummies (where to paste the code, etc), as I´m a beginner.

The site I want to do this in is: http://test.creatiburon.com/

Many thanks :)

Comment: As you can read in the header of this site, this site is dedicated to "WordPress Development". This is no place to post "do this job for me" requests. You might be better off at the wordpress.org support forums.

Comment: I had a look at the site, and this can purely be done with CSS, which makes this question off-topic

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article in the WP-Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More
Al you need is explained there. To style the read more link you need to know basic css.